# Jinja2 case switch for dynamic variable changes

Tags: python, jinja2

I have a template which I'm editing with Jinja and would like to know if I can set a certain variable based on some sort of case/switch.

For example, I have this config file:

```
[Service-Name]
Service_Name = hostname01

[Ports]
Ports = 22, 443, 8080

[Instance]
Instance_ID_IP = i-0asd589r52
#Instance_ID_IP = 192.168.1.1
```

The `Instance` section can accept either an `ID` or an `IP`.

- IDs are usually just a string that looks like this: i-0asd589r52
- IPs are regular addresses like 192.168.1.1

Somewhere in the template, I need to change a variable to work based on whether the config received an IP or an ID.

Here is a stripped down snippet of that area inside of my template:

```yaml
    {% for port in ports %}
    ElasticLoadBalancingV2TargetGroup{{ counter + loop.index0 }}:
        Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
        Properties:
            Port: !FindInMap [NLBPorts, Port{{ counter + loop.index0 }}, Port]
            TargetType: "instance" # here
            HealthyThresholdCount: 3
    {% endfor %}
```

In the line where it says `TargetType: "instance"` I need it to either say `instance` or `ip`.

I wasn't quite sure how to achieve this and whether it should be inside of the template, written with Jinja2 or inside of the script itself. Or maybe both?

Here is my script:

```py
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
import configparser

#Choose templates location and load to env variable
loader = FileSystemLoader('templates')
env = Environment(loader=loader)
configParser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
configFilePath = (r'endpoint.cfg')
configParser.read(configFilePath)

#Declaring variables from endpoint.cfg
service_name = configParser.get('Service-Name', 'Service_Name')
ports = configParser.get('Ports', 'Ports')
ports = tuple([int(port.strip()) for port in ports.split(',')])
instance_id_ip = configParser.get('Instance', 'Instance_ID_IP')

#Provide name of template
endpoint_service_template = env.get_template('endpointservice-template.yaml')

#Render templates
endpoint_service_result = endpoint_service_template.render({'service_name':service_name, 'ports':ports, 'instance_id_ip':instance_id_ip})
```

I'm not quite sure how to achieve what I'm trying to do. How do you set a switch that checks whether I entered an ID or an IP and then tell Jinja which one to use.

My approach was to use regex to determine whether it's an IP or not:

```py
import re

try:
    is_ip_address = [0<=int(x)<256 for x in re.split('\.',re.match(r'^\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+$',instance_id_ip).group(0))].count(True)==4
except:
    is_ip_address = None
```

I'm not sure how to continue from here. Assuming `instance_id_ip` is `None`, how do I tell Jinja that it's an ID and not an IP and vice versa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass `is_ip_address` into your template as another variable:

```
endpoint_service_result = endpoint_service_template.render({
  'service_name':service_name,
  'ports':ports,
  'instance_id_ip':instance_id_ip,
  'is_ip_address': is_ip_address,
})
```

And then use a conditional in your template to set the `TargetType`:

```
TargetType: "{'ip' if is_ip_address else 'instance'}"
```

Comment: Thank you! The correct line was `"{{ 'ip' if is_ip_address else 'instance' }}"`. I think you had a typo with the `is` is all. Thank you again.

Comment: Sorry about the typo!